# Why String normalization doesn't work in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The following code gives the expected result in .Net Framework and .Net core. But Xamarin Forms has no effect on it. What could be wrong?

```
var input = "\uD835\uDC00";// Renders as --> 
var output = input.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKC) ;//Tried all Forms
Console.WriteLine(output); // Expected -> "A" 
Console.WriteLine((int)output[0] == 0x41); // Expected -> True
```

**I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.726**

Comment: what framework is your project using?

Comment: @Jason I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.6/.Net Standard 2.1

Comment: This could be an issue of Mono and I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19855) in Github.

Comment: No problem, I will update here once get new information.